# Embedding a Prolog engine in Obj-C projects

Tags: c++, objective-c, prolog, embedded-language

I'm looking for a light-weight Prolog engine to be embedded in an Obj-C application under Mac OSX. 
In Java there are some excellent implementations with the characteristics I need: deployability, lightness, dynamic configurability, integration with Java and ease of interoperability.
Can you recommend something similar in C/C++?

---

After several searches I found YAProlog and reading [here](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/documentation.html#SEC177) it seems it can be used as library to be called from other programs. But (stupid questions):

1. I'm inexperienced with UNIX and I don't know exactly how to produce libyap.a file with those commands of the YAP manual...
2. Can I then copy libyap.a in my Xcode project and use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GProlog`](http://www.gprolog.org/#platform) supports Mac OS X (Darwin) and there's an installer for Mac OS X Leopard. And [here](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog065.html) you can read how to [call gprolog from C](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog071.html) (read also [this](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc380)). Then instead of using `gplc`, you can use `gcc` provided that you add the proper options for linking, which could be a bit "trickie" to be found; so you can produce object files with `gplc` and then glue everything together...

About YAP:

1) Usually package with autoconf are compiled simply with the following "sequence" of commands

```
./configure
make
```

A final `make install` should install everything and must be executed by a user having the rights to do so. The manual suggest the creation of an `ARCH` (ARCH.?) dir and doing everything from there (so, `../configure` instead of `./configure`).

The `configure` script accepts usually options, take a look at them. Check in particular where are `LIBDIR` and `YAPLIBDIR`.

So, once you have the source tarball (the `.tar.gz` of the source), you should dearchive it, a command like `tar -xzf Yap-5.1.3.tar.gz` works on GNU/Linux and the same `tar` should be also on Mac OS X...

Let's look at `./configure --help` and look if you see interesting option you want to use before proceeding.

Now, let's follow manual's suggestion (even if it looks odd to me;-))

```
mkdir ARCH.  # I would put GNUlinux, or maybe
             # the name must be exactly this?
cd ARCH.
../configure
```

You wait... and the directory gets populated of evrything needed for the next step. Take a look at the created `Makefile`, you see lines like

```
#
# where YAP should look for binary libraries
#
LIBDIR=$(EROOTDIR)/lib
YAPLIBDIR=$(EROOTDIR)/lib/Yap
```

Among the targets of the Makefile, I can read also `libYap.a`. So, try the `make` (I won't do that to check what can go wrong, also because I am on GNU/Linux and how I can solve problems could be different), at the end, you should obtain the `libYap.a`, and so, become "root" (administrator) and do

```
make install
```

In the `install` target (exactly `install_unix` for me) I read `$(INSTALL_DATA) -m 755 libYap.a $(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)` which means that your `.a` is installed and should be ready to be used by a compiler, provided you know where the lib is (and you know it, see above and remember the configure's options)

2) Of course you can copy it directly where you need it and use it "directly", but since it is "canonically" installed by the `make install`, use it the way you'd use any other "system wide" lib archive.

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog’s Foreign Language Interface section of the manual has an entry for [Embedding SWI-Prolog in other applications](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=embedded). As far as calling it from Objective C, it should be possible just as easily as calling any C code.

> ### 12.4.23 Embedding SWI-Prolog in other applications
>
> With embedded Prolog we refer to the situation where the‘main' program is not the Prolog application. Prolog is sometimes embedded in C, C++, Java or other languages to provide logic based services in a larger application. Embedding loads the Prolog engine as a library to the external language. Prolog itself only provides for embedding in the C language (compatible with C++). Embedding in Java is achieved using JPL using a C-glue between the Java and Prolog C interfaces.